# Upgrade script not working in magento custom module with product relationship

Tags: upgrade-script

I have created one install script **install-1.0.0.0.1.php** that is as below

```
$installer = $this;

$table = $installer->getConnection()
->newTable($installer->getTable('magentostudy_news/news'))

->addColumn('news_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'unsigned' => true,
    'identity' => true,
    'nullable' => false,
    'primary'  => true,
), 'Entity id')

->addColumn('title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
    'nullable' => true,
), 'Title')

->addColumn('author', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 63, array(
    'nullable' => true,
    'default'  => null,
), 'Author')
->addColumn('content', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '2M', array(
    'nullable' => true,
    'default'  => null,
), 'Content')
->addColumn('image', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
    'nullable' => true,
    'default'  => null,
), 'News image media path')
->addColumn('published_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE, null, array(
    'nullable' => true,
    'default'  => null,
), 'World publish date')
->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
    'nullable' => true,
    'default'  => null,
), 'Creation Time')
->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(
        $installer->getTable('magentostudy_news/news'),
        array('published_at'),
        Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX
    ),
    array('published_at'),
    array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX)
)
->setComment('News item');

$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

and here is my upgrade script **mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0.0.1-1.0.0.0.2.php** for    alter existing table to linking product with my table

```
  $installer = $this;

  $table = $installer->getConnection()

->addColumn($installer->getTable('magentostudy_news/news'),'product_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'unsigned'  => true,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'default'   => '0',
), 'Product ID')

->addColumn($installer->getTable('magentostudy_news/news'),'position', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    'default'   => '0',
), 'Position')

->addIndex($this->getIdxName('magentostudy_news/news', array('product_id')), array('product_id'))

->addForeignKey($this->getFkName('magentostudy_news/news', 'news_id', 'magentostudy_news/news', 'entity_id'), 'news_id', $this->getTable('magentostudy_news/news'), 'entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)

->addForeignKey($this->getFkName('magentostudy_news/news', 'product_id', 'catalog/product', 'entity_id'),    'product_id', $this->getTable('catalog/product'), 'entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
->setComment('News to Product Linkage Table');
```

When i run my URL its simply displaying blank page with no error messages There is some problem with upgrade script syntax only as install script working fine and when i remove upgrade script whole site working fine...plz help

Comment: try to activate the developer mode to see some error messages :)

Comment: I have enabled the developer mode and its showing this error in upgrade script file...

Fatal error: Call to a member function addColumn() on a non-object on line 22 that is in addColumn() method..

Answer (score 9):

I just had this problem. For me, the solution was to unchain the `addColumn` calls in your upgrade script. Like this:

```
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('magentostudy_news/news'),'product_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
    ), 'Product ID');

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('magentostudy_news/news'),'position', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
    ), 'Position');
```

The `addColumn` in this case returns the query results rather than the connection so they cannot be chained.

Try deleting your tables and simplifying your upgrade script. Add one field at a time so you can find out which column is causing the error.

Also, the error should be somewhere. Make sure you enable logging in the admin and check the `exception.log`.

Comment: thx. 2019, m2.3, still actual.